# Bootstrap alert like dismissable text

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Here is my requirement:
I have an html select list. When the user selects an option from the list, its text must be displayed beside it within a div. This text must function like a bootstrap dismissable alert.

Here is my approach:
The html code:

```
<div class = "col-md-4">
    <select id = "a1" onchange = addit('a1','r1')>
        <option>Potato</option>
        <option>Tomtato</option>
        <option>Spinach</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-8" id = "r1"></div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function addit(a,b){
    p1 = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
    p2 = '</div>';
    var t = document.getElementById(a);
    var an = t.options[t.selectedIndex].text;
    var vl = document.getElementById(b).innerHTML;
    if (vl.indexOf(an) == -1){
        document.getElementById(b).innerHTML += p1+an+p2;
    }
}
```

[image: I wish to see something like this:]

This isn't working. Nothing is showing up within the div element. When I right click and inspect (in Chrome), I can see these texts added.

The idea is when the user clicks on the x, the entry should be removed. What is the better approach?

Comment: Works for me, even without quotes around the `onclick` value: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rw8ase3u/

Comment: Yes Chris, I can see that it is working in the jsfiddle. Strangely, it isn't working for me within the bootstrap modal.

Comment: It is impossible for us to give you an update unless you show us your whole HTML content. Maybe the stylesheets or the JS haven't been linked properly.